# Template Starter Files

Tags: templates

I am looking for a starter kit just like the one of starterfiles.com. This domain name is not longer in use and doesn't provide the download file anymore. Is there any, not named EE, that why I can't find it, github project that provides a template starter kit for ExpressionEngine 2?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's on the waybackmachine http://web.archive.org/web/20110901211254/http://starterfiles.com/download

And it says the download is now on github
https://github.com/Jenn/ExpressionEngine-2-Starter-Files

Also, ExpressionEngine comes with a test project, you can install, called Agile-records. You can install a fresh copy of EE with that, onto your development station and have a look.

Some free turorials are available on http://www.train-ee.com/courseware/free-tutorials . If you like the course, consider taking a online course or training.

Comment: @GDmac: Thanks for sharing these. I think, it would be useful for me also.

Comment: there is also a dedicated StackExchange for ExpressionEngine over at: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/